# VBA ListView maintain previous value if new value is an empty string

Tags: excel, vba, listview

I'm having some trouble keeping the previous value in the SelectedItem of a ListView control.
I'm using EXCEL VBA UserForm to display table contents and allow for edits of the column.
However, I'm not able to maintain the previous value. After update, the value will be blank.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

```
Dim valBeforeEdit As String

Private Sub listviewOBJ_AfterLabelEdit(Cancel As Integer, NewString As String)
    If NewString <> "" Then
    'Update database with new value
        MsgBox "updated to " & NewString
    Else
        listviewOBJ.SelectedItem = valBeforeEdit
    'Put the value back to whatever it was before user erased it to blank ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub listviewOBJ_BeforeLabelEdit(Cancel As Integer)
    valBeforeEdit = listviewOBJ.SelectedItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to set it to the old value, just cancel the edit.

```
Private Sub listviewOBJ_AfterLabelEdit(Cancel As Integer, NewString As String)
    If NewString <> "" Then
    'Update database with new value
        MsgBox "updated to " & NewString
    Else
        Cancel = true  '<-- This cancels the edit, keeping whatever the value was before it was set to "" by the user.
    'Put the value back to whatever it was before user erased it to blank ""
    End If
End Sub
```